# adding Python to docker-compose containers

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I have a web app runs on ubuntu containers, the `docker-compose.yml` as below:

```
services:
    mysql: ...
    api: ...
    vue: ...
```

Now I want to use python script in my app, so I thought I might need to create a new folder with a new `Dockerfile` ?

```
FROM python:3.6.1-alpine
ADD . /code
WORKDIR /code
```

And include it as a new service in the `docker-compose.yml`?

**Or** should I tell docker to install python by adding `apt-get install python` in old `Dockerfile`?

Comment: Definitely the second one.

Comment: It depends. Is your app service yet existing? If yes, include python in this service. If not, create new python service.

Comment: When you say you want to use python in your app, you mean in the `api` service of your compose or in a new service?

Comment: @zigarn I want to use it in `api` service

Comment: @StoneSu As you want to use it inside `api` service, best way is `apt-get install python` in old `Dockerfile`